# How do I construct the click event (involves jQuery selectors)

Tags: jquery, css

I programmatically build a three-level set of DIVs.

Category A
    (Title1)
        (Content)
    (Title2)
        (Content)
Category B
Category C

By default, I set levels 2 and below (titles and content) to display:none.
With this code, I show all titles belonging to the category clicked:

```
    $("#catA").on("click", function() {
        $("#catA .itemTitle").css("display", "block");
    });
    ...
```

Now what I want to do is to show the content just for the title clicked. That seems to have exceeded my knowledge of selectors! Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show your html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to bind the click event to the `.itemTitle` and show the next content of it, (*If you are using jQuery then no need to use display block to show the hidden element simply you can use `show()` method*):

```
$('.itemTitle').on('click', function(){
  $(this).next('.content').show();
});  //---------^^^^^^^^-------------my assumption of class change to yours
```

Comment: yes! this is just an assumption as OP has not posted any html markup and it looks like he has itemTitle div first then content div.

Comment: _By default, I set levels 2 and below (titles and content) to display:none._ this line made me to assume something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".itemTitle").on("click", function() {
        $(".itemTitle >.content").css("display", "block");
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, Somnath. With my interpretation of Jai's suggestion, here is what now works:  
$("#catA").on("click", function() {
  $("#catA .itemTitle").css("display", "block");
  $("#catA .itemTitle").on("click", function() {
    $(this).next(".itemContent").css("display", "block");
  });
});
Is that what you intend, as well?